# Endroid qrcode Twig error when including a slash in the url (Symfony 5)

Tags: symfony, twig, qr-code

I'm trying to use [endroid/qr-code-bundle](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code-bundle) in a Symfony 5 project.

In Twig,
`<img src="{{ qr_code_url('www.test.com') }}"/>` works fine and generates the image.

However, including a slash in the url, like

`<img src="{{ qr_code_url('www.test.com/something') }}"/>`

gives me an error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "data" for route "qr_code_generate" must match "[^/]++" ("www.test.com/something" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

Any hint?

Comment: Did you try with protocol like "https://www.test.com/something"?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is triggered by the slash.

Comment: ok. Did you try to url_encode the url like `{{ qr_code_url('www.test.com/something'|url_encode) }}` https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/url_encode.html ?

Comment: I also did that. Then it passes the encoded url to he qr code, and when scanning the qr the browser does not decode it and fails as well